# Prevent Safari from hiding -webkit-input-placeholder?

Tags: html, css, safari, css-selectors, pseudo-element

When I add valid text to the input Safari overrides my ::-webkit-input-placeholder styling with "display: none !important;" Is there any way to prevent Safari from hiding the placeholder?

```
<div pseudo="-webkit-input-placeholder" style="display: none !important; text-overflow: clip;">First Name</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want the placeholder to be hidden?

Comment: Try https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/ 
becouse placeholder must work in safari :) 

http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

Comment: @DivineComedian - my reasoning was to create a floating label effect with placeholder. But I ended up using an actual <label> element.